# Gaussian blur with variance shadow map

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm implementing variance shadow maps following this article http://fabiensanglard.net/shadowmappingVSM/ I'm using a deferred renderer and at the moment I have managed to implement vsm with linear filtering. The results are ok but I can't seem to apply the gaussian filter to the shadows to create soft shadows. 
The following code shows how I am setting up the shadow frame buffer:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, shadow_fbo_);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < scene_->getAllSpotLights().size(); i++)
{
    SceneModel::SpotLight spotlight = scene_->getAllSpotLights()[i];    
    if (spotlight.getCastShadow())
    {
        GLuint shadow_map_tex;
        glGenTextures(1, &shadow_map_tex);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadow_map_tex);
        SetShadowTextureSettings();

        shadow_maps_.insert(std::pair<int, GLuint>(i, shadow_map_tex)); 

        GLuint blurred_map_tex;
        glGenTextures(1, &blurred_map_tex);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, blurred_map_tex);
        SetShadowTextureSettings();

        blurred_shadow_maps_.insert(std::pair<int, GLuint>(i, blurred_map_tex));
    }
}

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadow_maps_[0], 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, blurred_shadow_maps_[0], 0);

//rbo depth attatchment 
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, shadow_rbo_);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, shadow_rbo_);

ReportErrorInFrameBuffer(framebuffer_status, "Shadow");
```

The SetShadowTextureSettings() function is:

```
 void SetShadowTextureSettings()
 {
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RG32F, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RG, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
     glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
     glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
}
```

I first render from the point of the light, then attempt to blur the shadows created, then render the scene as normal. It is the blurring that doesn't seem to be working or having any effect on the shadows. Below shows the gaussian shaders.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout(location=0) in vec3 vertex_position;

void main(void) 
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position, 1);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D sampler_world_shadow;
uniform vec2 blurScale;

out vec4 fragment_colour;

const vec2 gaussianFilter[7] = vec2[]
( 
    vec2(-3.0, 0.015625),
    vec2(-2.0, 0.09375),
    vec2(-1.0, 0.234375),
    vec2(0.0,  0.3125),
    vec2(1.0,  0.234375),
    vec2(2.0,  0.09375),
    vec2(3.0,  0.015625)
);

void main()
{   
    vec2 coord = vec2(gl_FragCoord.xy);
    vec3 colour = vec3(0.0);
    float x = 0.0;
    float y = 0.0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    {
        x = coord.x + gaussianFilter[i].x * blurScale.x;
        y =  coord.y + gaussianFilter[i].x * blurScale.y;
        colour += texture(sampler_world_shadow, vec2(x, y)) * gaussianFilter[i].y;
    }

    fragment_colour = vec4(colour,1);
}
```

The following code shows how I am attempting to do the blur on the shadows. Switching between the two colour attachments.

```
void BlurShadow()
{
    int blur_amount = 2;
    for (std::pair<int, GLuint> pair : shadow_maps_)
    {
        //Blur horizontally
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, blurred_shadow_maps_[pair.first], 0);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pair.second);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shadow_blur_program_, "sampler_world_shadow"), 4);

        glm::vec2 blur = glm::vec2((1.0 / SHADOW_WIDTH) * blur_amount, 0.0);
        glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(shadow_blur_program_, "blurScale"), 1, glm::value_ptr(blur));

        glBindVertexArray(light_quad_mesh_.vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

        //Blur vertically
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, pair.second, 0);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, blurred_shadow_maps_[pair.first]);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shadow_blur_program_, "sampler_world_shadow"), 4);

        blur = glm::vec2(0.0, (1.0 / SHADOW_WIDTH) * blur_amount);
        glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(shadow_blur_program_, "blurScale"), 1, glm::value_ptr(blur));

        glBindVertexArray(light_quad_mesh_.vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    }
}
```

overall steps:

```
//SHADOWS render to depth map
glUseProgram(shadow_program_);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, shadow_fbo_);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT);

//Cull front face to help with anti aliasing in shadows
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);

DrawToShadowDepthMap();

glCullFace(GL_BACK);

//GAUSSIAN BLUR on shadow maps 
glUseProgram(shadow_blur_program_);

BlurShadow();

glViewport(0, 0, viewport_size[2], viewport_size[3]);
//other lighting calculations /rendering scene
```

My thoughts are that something is going wrong within the blurring function or the gaussian shaders but I cannot figure out what. If I comment out the vertical blurring stage and blit color attachment 1 to the screen it's as if the shadow is just copied from color attachment 0.

Any help would be appreciated.